# RuntimeError: Couldn't connect to selenium server

Tags: selenium, jasmine, webdriver-io

I have a web app that I am trying to test with [WebDriver IO](http://webdriver.io/) via Jasmine. Currently, I've setup my test like this:

```
'use strict';

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var client = null;

var rootUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

describe('Site', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {       
    // Initialize the test client. Use PhantomJS
    client = webdriverio.remote({ desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'phantomjs' } });

    client.init()
      .url(rootUrl)
      .then(done);
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    client.end(done);       
  });

  // Ensure that the page properly loads.
  it('Should load', function(done) {
    client
      .getTitle()
      .then(function(title) {
        expect(title).toBe('Welcome');          
        done();         
      })
    ;
  });   
});
```

I'm running the this test from gulp via the following task:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src(input.tests)
    .pipe(jasmine())
  ;
});
```

When I run this task via `gulp test`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Couldn't connect to selenium server
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything about starting the selenium server standalone.
You need to download the jar and run it.

You can do this by executing

```
$ curl -O http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar
```

And then

`$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar`

Then you can call the server in your tests with

```
webdriverio
.remote(options)
.init()
.url('http://www.google.com')
.title(function(err, res) {
    console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
})
.end();
```